# How to boot UbuntuMate from usb (micro-SD) on VirtualBox [Mac OS X]

Tags: usb, virtualbox, usb-drive, ubuntu-mate

I have flashed UbuntuMate on my micro-SD, which could be used to boot my Odroid XU4 board. It works perfectly on the Odroid Board for prototyping but Now I want to boot UbuntuMate from VritualBox on my Mac OS X as well.

I followed this tutorial: http://innov8tiv.com/boot-virtual-machine-usb-virtualbox-guide/ and created .vmdk file to be able to boot from the usb drive (micro-SD attached). But when I am trying to boot from the USB (micro-SD) it is giving me the following error:

> VD: error VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED opening image file

Any idea how I can boot UbuntuMate on VirtualBox from my bootable USB (micro-SD)?

P.S. Using -- VirtualBox Graphical User Interface
Version 5.2.14 r123301 (Qt5.6.3)
Mac Os X: High Sierra

Answer (score 1):

Usually you do not install OS for Odroids, you burn pre-compiled image so are you trying to boot your VM from Odroids Ubuntu-mate disk image? If so it won't work, one of the reasons is different CPU architecture.

If you are trying to install Ubuntu Mate from bootable sd-card it is much easier to do so with .iso image or adding SD card as removable disk in settings and then on boot choose the right disk.

Comment: Remove the first sentence, this post would look like a fine answer to me.